# Exports whole object with functions

Tags: node.js

i tried found answer in stackoverflow and can't find any answer about this
 i just started learning NodeJS . and i got a question, is there any way how can i exports whole object with his functions or i can exports only functions of object?

thanks for advice!

when i try it i got error like this

`TypeError: object is not a function`

i got simple code like this :

animal.js

```
var Animal = {

   name : null,

   setName : function(name) {

      this.name = name;

   },

   getName : function() {

       console.log("name of animal is " + this.name);
   }

}


exports.Animal = Animal;
```

and server.js

```
  var animal = require('./animal');

  var ani = new animal.Animal();
```

Comment: You can't use an object as a function, do `var Animal = function () { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) expects a `Function` while `Animal` is a plain `Object`.

Though, with the `Object`, you could use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create instances:

```
// ...

var ani = Object.create(animal.Animal);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to define `Animal` as a constructor `Function`:

```
function Animal() {
    this.name = null;

    // ...
}

exports.Animal = Animal;
```

---

Note: Depending on precisely what you want to accomplish, `Function`s are a type of `Object` and can hold additional properties.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name || Animal.defaultName;
}

Animal.defaultName = null;
```